# Illegalstateexception content view not yet created in listfragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

The problem is, when I make a search into the listfragment, it works. When I close it and open again and do another search, the exception appears. In the developers options I choose to not maintain the activities.

I guess the references of the layout are lost when the app wakes up, but have no idea why.

What can I do?

This is my code

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    listAdapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), adArrayList);
    setListAdapter(listAdapter);
    getListView().setOnScrollListener(this);

}

@Override public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view,savedInstanceState);

    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) view;

    mPullToRefreshLayout = new PullToRefreshLayout(viewGroup.getContext());

    ActionBarPullToRefresh.from(getActivity())

            .insertLayoutInto(viewGroup)

            .theseChildrenArePullable(android.R.id.list)

            .listener(this)

            .setup(mPullToRefreshLayout);
}

@Override
    public void onResume() {
        pagination = 0;
        getAds("");
        super.onResume() ;

    }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) listView.getParent();

    // Remove ListView and add CustomView in its place
    int listViewIndex = parent.indexOfChild(listView);
    parent.removeViewAt(listViewIndex);
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.list_frag, container, false);
    parent.addView(linearLayout , listViewIndex,
            listView.getLayoutParams());

    listView.setDrawSelectorOnTop(false);
    listView.setDivider(null);
    listView.setDividerHeight(0);

    return view;
}
```

And this is the method I use to get the data from the server

```
 //the next method use retrofit
        public void getAds(String productSearch){
                isLoadingMoreAds = true;

                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                    mPullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                } else{
                    setListShown(false);
                }
                Services services= Utils.getRESTAdapter();

                services.getSearch(new Callback<AdsList>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(AdsList adsList, Response response) {
                        try{
                            setListShown(true);
                            mPullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshComplete();
                            updateView(adsList.getAd());
                            isLoadingMoreAds = false;
                        }catch(IllegalStateException e){
                            Log.e("Exception", "ListFragment ya no existe");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

                        isLoadingMoreAds = false;

                        mPullToRefreshLayout.setRefreshComplete();

                        updateView(new ArrayList<Ad>());

                        setListShown(true);

                        Log.e("Error", "Failure at get ads");

                    }
                });

            }
```

Comment: why do you have this  `listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);` when you already have `listView = getListView();`

Comment: I forgot to remove that line. I was trying to force the app to get the listview in each event